# How to refer to history lines in shell script?

Tags: linux, for-loop, ubuntu, reference, sh

So what I want to do is to reproduce multiple lines used previously, using for loop and refers to history lines.
Like I made a dir, then cd into dir, and then make a file, then I delete everything, and I want to reproduce the dir with the file in it without deleting, like I want to use !1 !2 !3, but how?
I tried these methods:

```
for i in {1..3}
do   
   !$i
done
```

But i've tried callint the ! command with $! and "!", of course neither worked. I also tried fc $i but nothing happened. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`man bash` says under "HISTORY EXPANSION":

> History expansion is performed immediately after a complete line is read, before the shell      breaks it into words.

This means the history expansion happens before variable expansion, i.e. you can't use a variable instead of the number after `!` because the shell still doesn't know what value it has.

Moreover, non-interactive shells have history expansion disabled by default. You can change it with `set`, see e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o history
set -H
ls
!-1
```